# Criteria based duplicate mark within rows of IP addresses in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, duplicates

**How can I mark duplicate ip addressees based on some criteria?**

For example ip adressess sharing same values in in all, but last part of the address (`100.100.10.***`), or ips sharing same values in all but last two digits (`100.100.10.1**`) - see 3 scenario examples below.

So far, I managed to find and mark full duplicates of any row:

```
require(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(ip = c("100.100.10.100","100.100.10.101", "100.100.10.102", "100.100.10.113",
                          "100.100.10.100", "100.100.10.200", "100.100.11.100", "100.100.10.101",
                          "100.100.10.10", "100.100.10.1"))

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(ip.dupe =ifelse(duplicated(ip) | duplicated(ip, fromLast = TRUE), 1,0))
data

ip ip.dupe
1  100.100.10.100       1
2  100.100.10.101       1
3  100.100.10.102       0
4  100.100.10.113       0
5  100.100.10.100       1
6  100.100.10.200       0
7  100.100.11.100       0
8  100.100.10.101       1
9   100.100.10.10       0
10   100.100.10.1       0
```

I'm looking for ways to achieve the following scenarios:

```
# Scenario 2 - dupes are matches in 100.100.10.***

ip ip.dupe
1  100.100.10.100       1
2  100.100.10.101       1
3  100.100.10.102       1
4  100.100.10.113       1
5  100.100.10.100       1
6  100.100.10.200       1
7  100.100.11.100       0
8  100.100.10.101       1
9   100.100.10.10       1
10   100.100.10.1       1

# Scenario 3 - dupes are matches in 100.100.10.1**

ip ip.dupe
1  100.100.10.100       1
2  100.100.10.101       1
3  100.100.10.102       1
4  100.100.10.113       1
5  100.100.10.100       1
6  100.100.10.200       0
7  100.100.11.100       0
8  100.100.10.101       1
9   100.100.10.10       0
10   100.100.10.1       0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach through grouping with regular expressions:

Scenario 2

```
data %>%
  group_by(prefix = str_replace(ip,"\\.[0-9]+$","")) %>%
  mutate(ip.dupe = c(0,rep(1,n() -1))) 
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   prefix [2]
   ip             prefix     ip.dupe
   <fct>          <chr>        <dbl>
 1 100.100.10.100 100.100.10       0
 2 100.100.10.101 100.100.10       1
 3 100.100.10.102 100.100.10       1
 4 100.100.10.113 100.100.10       1
 5 100.100.10.100 100.100.10       1
 6 100.100.10.200 100.100.10       1
 7 100.100.11.100 100.100.11       0
 8 100.100.10.101 100.100.10       1
 9 100.100.10.10  100.100.10       1
10 100.100.10.1   100.100.10       1
```

Here's an expression for Scenario 3:

```
data %>%
  group_by(prefix = str_replace(ip,"(?<=\\.[0-9])[0-9]+$","")) %>%
  mutate(ip.dupe = c(0,rep(1,n() -1))) 
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   prefix [3]
   ip             prefix       ip.dupe
   <fct>          <chr>          <dbl>
 1 100.100.10.100 100.100.10.1       0
 2 100.100.10.101 100.100.10.1       1
 3 100.100.10.102 100.100.10.1       1
 4 100.100.10.113 100.100.10.1       1
 5 100.100.10.100 100.100.10.1       1
 6 100.100.10.200 100.100.10.2       0
 7 100.100.11.100 100.100.11.1       0
 8 100.100.10.101 100.100.10.1       1
 9 100.100.10.10  100.100.10.1       1
10 100.100.10.1   100.100.10.1       1
```

Note that `(?<=)` encloses a positive lookbehind group.

Comment: Thanks Ian, i guess this approach requires creating a separate prefix column. If possible i'd like to avoid that.

Comment: You can trivially remove it with `dplyr::select(-prefix)`. I left it in there for you to visualize what is happening.

Comment: Got it, thanks :) I thought there might be a simpler solution that would not involve creating this prefix at all, but after all I don't mind it being there :)

Comment: You could use only `mutate` and `rle`, but then you have to worry that the IPs are ordered correctly.